# Woocommerce Conditional Product Tabs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Okay, I'm trying to show certain tab content depending on what category a product is listed in.

I have created a custom "Size Chart" tab and want to show for example:

- Footwear size chart when product is in "Footwear" category
- Clothing size chart when product is in "Clothing" category
- No size chart when product is in "Accessories" category.

I've created a custom tab like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tabs', 98 );

function woo_rename_tabs( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['new_tab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'Size Chart', 'woocommerce' ),
    'priority'  => 55,
    'callback'  => 'woo_tab_content'
);

return $tabs;

}
```

Then added the custom tab content like this:

```
function woo_tab_content() {

    echo 'This is the size chart';

}
```

Does anyone know how to add a conditional statement to this code to allow me to specify what content is displayed depending on what category a product is placed in i.e.

```
is_product_category( 'footwear' )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in you woo_tab_content function simple add what you have done above so it would like this this:

```
function woo_tab_content() {

    if (is_product_category( 'footwear' )){

        echo 'This is the size chart';

    } else {

        //do something else

    }

}
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this with the question and I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to fix it using the following code:

```
function woo_tab_content() {

global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;

if ( in_array( 'clothing', $categories ) ) {

    echo 'this is the clothing tab content!';

} elseif ( in_array( 'shoes', $categories ) ) {

    echo 'this is the shoes tab content!';

} else {
    echo 'all other tabs';
}

}
```

It turns out that is_product_category does not work for the single product pages. Only for the category page itself.